# Elastic MapReduce fails with: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: elastic-map-reduce

I'm trying to run a native binary, compiled on my x86 Debian Squeeze box (to match the Amazon AMI), and I'm consistently getting this weird error

`/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201206011019_0001/attempt_201206011019_0001_m_000000_0/work/./word-count: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

It's puzzling since word-count is a binary executable. Anyone know what part of the system is complaining here? Is the OS trying to look for some magic bytes in the beginning of the binary file and not finding them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a while ago but if I remember correctly the issue was that the binary I was trying to run was compiled on OS X, not a matching OS/arch (i.e. Debian).